# Typescript assign initial empty array value to custom array type

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
export type CarList = Array<ICar> & {
    [index: string]: ICar
}
```

and I would like to use it like this:

```
    ...
    let cars: CarList = []

    for (item in items) {
        cars['some-value'].push(item)
    }
    ...
```

The problem is that, the first line throws an error:

```
Error:(79, 13) TS2322: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'CarList '.
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '{ [index: string]: ICar; }'.
Index signature is missing in type 'never[]'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: type CarList<T> = {
        [index: number]: T
    }
    
    let cars: CarList<string> = ['car']

or describe what array of cars looks like.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to assign an empty array to cars, so ['car'] is not good for me. The values come from the items collection in the for loop.

Comment: let cars: CarList = [] as any will work, but without expected look at cars i can't make a type for you